# Track eclipse plug-in usage

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I want to track a set of custom plug-ins usage in Eclipse.. Like how many time they clicked the menu option etc...

Do you guys have any clue / suggestions?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Yea, there is a Usage Data Collector that you can use that does exactly this. 
http://www.eclipse.org/epp/usagedata/

I haven't used it myself, so I'm not sure if this is working like you want out of the box, or if you will have to make some adaptations.